# LPCWSTR ERROR C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type

Tags: c++, lpcwstr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include "sharedmemory.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

#define MAP_OBJECT_NAME "$pcars2$"

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    HANDLE fileHandle = OpenFileMapping(PAGE_READONLY, FALSE, MAP_OBJECT_NAME);
```

I am relatively new to C++, and I happened across this road block. When I'm trying to place any `#define` into an argument like on the `OpenFileMapping()` line, I get an error saying:

> C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type

My end goal with this program is to send a UDP message that grabs data from shared memory.

Is this a result of me using `void` instead of `int`? I don't know.

Comment: `LPCWSTR` stands for "Long Pointer to Chars (Wide) representing a STRing".

Comment: Well to your credit, at least you didn't try to C-style cast your way out of the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TCHAR` is defined as either `wchar_t` or `char`, depending on whether `UNICODE` has been defined or not in your project setup, respectively.

`OpenFileMapping()` is a `TCHAR`-based preprocessor macro.  It is defined as taking a `const TCHAR*` pointer to a null-terminated string in its 3rd parameter.

In reality, what happens is that `OpenFileMapping()` maps to either the [`OpenFileMappingA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilemappinga) (ANSI) or [`OpenFileMappingW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilemappingw) (Unicode) function, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined:

```cpp
// in winbase.h
WINBASEAPI
__out
HANDLE
WINAPI
OpenFileMappingA(
    __in DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    __in BOOL bInheritHandle,
    __in LPCSTR lpName
    );
WINBASEAPI
__out
HANDLE
WINAPI
OpenFileMappingW(
    __in DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    __in BOOL bInheritHandle,
    __in LPCWSTR lpName
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define OpenFileMapping  OpenFileMappingW
#else
#define OpenFileMapping  OpenFileMappingA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Most legacy Win32 APIs that deal with character data are separated into `A` and `W` versions like this.  Newer APIs introduced in recent years tend to be Unicode-only.

In your case, `UNICODE` is defined, so you are trying to pass a narrow string literal (`const char[]`) where a Unicode string (const `wchar_t*`) is expected. That is why you are getting a type mismatch error.

When using character/string literals with `TCHAR`-based APIs, use the [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro to ensure the literal uses the correct character type that `TCHAR` actually maps to, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include "sharedmemory.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

#define MAP_OBJECT_NAME TEXT("$pcars2$") // <-- HERE

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    HANDLE fileHandle = OpenFileMapping(PAGE_READONLY, FALSE, MAP_OBJECT_NAME);
```

Which is effectively doing the following when `UNICODE` is defined:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include "sharedmemory.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

#define MAP_OBJECT_NAME L"$pcars2$"

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    HANDLE fileHandle = OpenFileMappingW(PAGE_READONLY, FALSE, MAP_OBJECT_NAME);
```

And doing this when `UNICODE` is not defined:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include "sharedmemory.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

#define MAP_OBJECT_NAME "$pcars2$"

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    HANDLE fileHandle = OpenFileMappingA(PAGE_READONLY, FALSE, MAP_OBJECT_NAME);
```

However, modern coding practices should not rely on `TCHAR` APIs at all.  They are meant for backwards compatibility with legacy Win9x/ME code during Microsoft's push to migrate users to adopt Unicode in the early 2000s.  You should use the ANSI or Unicode functions directly instead as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your strings in the `_T()` macro. It will convert LPCSTR strings to LPCWSTR when Unicode WinAPI is selected in project settings.

```
#define MAP_OBJECT_NAME _T("$pcars2$")
```

Comment: `OpenFileMapping()` is a Win32 API macro, not a C runtime function. You should use the `TEXT()` macro for literals that are meant to be used with the Win32 API, and the `_T()` macro for literals that are meant to be used with the C runtime library. `TEXT()` and `_T()` are *generally* inter-changable, because `TCHAR` (Win32) and `_TCHAR` (C) are, but I would not suggest writing code that crosses library boundaries like that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to change `OpenFileMapping` to `OpenFileMappingA` . This version takes a narrow character string which you are providing.